# python pandas - is there any faster way to do explode operation according to the requirement

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

The code  is as following
the input dataframe is
[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 'Falconiformes', 2),
                      ('bird', 'Psittaciformes', 4),
                      ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 8),
                     ('mammal', 'Primates', np.nan),
                    ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 12)],
                     index=['falcon', 'parrot', 'lion', 'monkey', 'leopard'],
                    columns=('class', 'order', 'count'))

unique_class= df['class'].unique().tolist()
temp_list = []
for i in range(len(unique_class)):         
    temp =df[df['class']==unique_class[i]].reset_index(drop=True)
    pipe_values= temp['order'].values.tolist()
    count_values=temp['count'].values.tolist()
    Stri= "|".join(pipe_values)
    for j in range(len(pipe_values)):
        df1=temp[:1]
        df1['order']=  Stri         
        df1['count'+str(j)]=count_values[j]
        
    
    temp_list.append(df1)
    final = pd.concat(temp_list)
    final
```

the output is
[image]

The problem is when huge data come - around 1 million - the process is slow, is there any other logic or inbuild function  in  pandas that we can do, also how will I do that using vaex library
thanks

Comment: can you share text of dataframe than images

Comment: there the input example one in the code sample

Comment: Us who don't live in India have no idea what are "lakhs". So please don't use Indian words here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it within Pandas (not sure why you need to combine the data this way):

Groupby on `class`, convert everything to string, and aggregate with python's `str.join`:

```
temp = df.set_index('class').astype(str).groupby(level=[0]).agg("|".join)
```

Split `count` into individual columns and recombine with `temp`:

```
 anoda = (temp['count'].str.split("|", expand=True)
                       .astype(float)
                       .add_prefix('count')
          )

temp.join(anoda).drop(columns='count')


                               order  count0  count1  count2
class                                                       
bird    Falconiformes|Psittaciformes     2.0     4.0     NaN
mammal  Carnivora|Primates|Carnivora     8.0     NaN    12.0
```